# ACL in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, acl, hgrc

I'm trying to get ACL working in Mercurial. Now, I'm not positive that it will work at all because I'm using hg 1.5.1. (I'm working on figuring out who I have to talk to to get someone to upgrade that for me)

Assuming  that 1.5.1 will support it, my hgrc file looks like:

```
[extensions]
acl =

[hooks]

# Use this if you want to check access restrictions at commit time
pretxncommit = python:hgext.acl.hook

# Use this if you want to check access restrictions for pull, push,
# bundle and serve.
pretxnchangegroup = python:hgext.acl.hook

[acl]
# Check whether the source of incoming changes is in this list where
# "serve" == ssh or http, and "push", "pull" and "bundle" are the
# corresponding hg commands.

sources = serve push pull
```

etc

I'm getting:

```
error: pretxnchangegroup hook failed: acl: access denied for changeset 242c80d5c009
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: acl: access denied for changeset 242c80d5c009
```

Currently, I'm just doing this on a tiny non-server repo, but eventually this will be on a normal large HTTPS server...

thanks

EDIT: [ changed hgrc file]
Ok, now I seem to be 1/2 there. When I try to push on a branch I'm not allowed to, I get:

```
error: pretxnchangegroup.acl hook failed: acl: user "brian_postow" not allowed on branch "branch-b" (changeset "597eddef10a1")
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: acl: user "brian_postow" not allowed on branch "branch-b" (changeset "597eddef10a1")
```

Which looks correct (maybe?) However, when I push from a branch that I *AM* allowed to, I get:

```
error: pretxnchangegroup.acl hook failed: acl: access denied for changeset 242c80d5c009
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: acl: access denied for changeset 242c80d5c009
```

so, I still don't appear to be able to push... Any ideas?

Comment: What exact command are you using when pushing both when it works and when it doesn't.  Can we see the 'hg log' output for "242c80d5c009".  Please provide the acl.* sections of your config file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I solved this problem. The problem was that I had [acl allow] but nothing in it... I thought that branches.allow would supercede allow, but I guess not.

thanks.!